# The altitudes of a triangle are 10,12,15 cm each.Find the semiperimeter of the triangle.

Tags: geometry

The altitudes of a triangle are 10,12,15 cm each.Find the semiperimeter of the triangle.

I think this can be easily done by a herons formula equation but i want other easy methods to do this sum.

Comment: What is semi perimeter?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz It's understood to be $s = \frac{a+b+c}{2}$

Comment: nope  sorry my mistake can be done easily by herons formula .But will be a lengthy process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Δ$ be the area of triangle. Let $h_a=10, h_b=12, h_c=15$ be lengths of perpendiculars dropped on sides $a, b, c$ respectively.  Hence we have 
$$Δ=\frac {1}{2}\cdot 10 \cdot a=\frac {1}{2}\cdot 12 \cdot b=\frac {1}{2}\cdot 15 \cdot c $$
Hence let $$10a=12b=15c=k$$
For some constant k. Hence we have $$a=\frac {k}{10} ; b=\frac {k}{12}; c=\frac {k}{15}; s=\frac {k}{8}$$

By cosine rule we get $\cos A= \frac {1}{8}$
We also know that $$Δ=\frac {1}{2} \cdot bc \sin A = \frac {1}{2} \cdot 12\cdot b$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin A =\frac {180}{k}$$

Using these information we get the equation as $$\frac {\sqrt {63}}{8}= \frac {180}{k}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac {k}{8}= \frac {60}{\sqrt 7}$$
$$\Rightarrow s=\frac {k}{8}= \frac {60}{\sqrt {7}}$$

Hope it helped.

Comment: From the cosine law we get: $$\cos A={b^2+c^2-a^2\over2bc}={1\over8}$$, which then gives the correct result.

Comment: @Aretino Thanks a lot buddy

Answer (score 3):

I do not get how the Cauchy-Schwarz *inequality* can be used to derive a length in explicit terms, but the lenghts of the altitudes give the area of the triangle through Heron's formula:

$$ \Delta = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)} $$
$$ \frac{1}{\Delta} = \sqrt{\left(\tfrac{1}{h_a}+\tfrac{1}{h_b}+\tfrac{1}{h_b}\right)\left(-\tfrac{1}{h_a}+\tfrac{1}{h_b}+\tfrac{1}{h_b}\right)\left(\tfrac{1}{h_a}-\tfrac{1}{h_b}+\tfrac{1}{h_b}\right)\left(\tfrac{1}{h_a}+\tfrac{1}{h_b}-\tfrac{1}{h_c}\right)}$$
hence $\Delta=\frac{240}{\sqrt{7}}$ and $a,b,c\in\left\{\frac{48}{\sqrt{7}},\frac{40}{\sqrt{7}},\frac{32}{\sqrt{7}}\right\}$, from which
$$ s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}=\color{red}{\frac{60}{\sqrt{7}}}.$$

Comment: i good solution!

Comment: Yes its a good soultion  and +1 for your effort but can you done one without use of herons formula

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I am getting a different answer. Can you please check once what is going wrong in my answer.

Comment: @Manthanein: I do not have the time for checking your computations, but as a counter-proof we may simply check what happens in a triangle with side lengths $4,5,6$ and scale accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, in such a triangle the area is $\frac{15}{4}\sqrt{7}$ and the heights are $10,12,15$ times $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{8}$, so my computation is correct.